# process synchronization with 2 pipes

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe

I'm doing an assignment. I need to write a C program with one child, and then father and child have to print to stdout one line for each.
Basically I want something like this:

```
I'm the father
I'm the child
I'm the father
I'm the child
I'm the father
I'm the child
...
```

I'm allowed to only use two pipes for process communication.
This is what I've written:

```
int par_read = pipe1[0];
int par_write = pipe2[1];
int cld_read = pipe2[0];
int cld_write = pipe1[1];

char w;

if (fork()) // par
{
    close(cld_read);
    close(cld_write);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("I'm the father\n");

        if (write(par_write, &w, 1) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error on par_write: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (read(par_read, &w, 1) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error on par_read: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

}
else    // cld
{
    close(par_read);
    close(par_write);

    while(1)
    {
        if (read(cld_read, &w, 1) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error on cld_read: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("I'm the child\n");

        if (write(cld_write, &w, 1) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error on cld_write: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/AA1R17m7).
The problem is that the two processes start working correctly only after a few hundred lines. The first lines are full of "I'm the father". I also checked it counting the lines:

```
$ ./ex > ex_out
$ cat ex_out | wc -l
40960
$ cat ex_out | uniq | wc - l
255
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` output might not get written immediately but get delayed until a buffer is full because `printf` and other functions from `stdio.h` use buffered output by default.

Try one of the following:

- add `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` before the `fork()` to disable buffering or
- use `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` or
- use `write` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Actually, output to `stdout` is *line* buffered "by default", But when connected to a pipe it's *fully* buffered.